# A complex Rails find based on associations and sometimes the id is nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rails app and I want to make it generate a report

I have a Log, Customer, User and Project models.

Log can belong to project and customer, and always belongs to a user.

When I generate the report. I can for instance select the user and get all the logs on that user. When I select user and project I want to get the log that are associated to the user and project.

This was my initial try:

```
Log.where(user_id: params[:user_id],project _id: params[:project_id],customer_id: params[:customer_id]
```

The problem is that if I want the logs for a particular project or customer, the params[:user_id] is nil and it errors out

So secound try

```
class Log < ActiveRecord::Base
    def self.user_try(user)
        if user
          where(user_id: user)
        else
          where("end_time IS NOT NULL")
        end
    end 
   #corresponding methods for project and customer
end
```

I have to have the ugly if..else statement cause if user is nil it errors out the `where("end_time IS NOT NULL")` find is just always true.

The find is now like this

```
Log.user_try(params[:user_id])
   .project_try(params[:project_id])
   .customer_try(params[:customer_id])
```

This works, but I really don't like the code.

Third try is where I am stuck

I am trying to make on method that does the work for all three "user_try" methods by passing the params in to the method as a hash.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In controller

```
Log.try_find_logs(user_id: params[:user_id],
                  project_id: params[:project_id], 
                  customer_id: params[:customer_id])
```

In the model I map over the hash. This gives me a array of arrays. I inject the & operator and get the logs that have correct ids even if I don't have some of the parameters.

```
class Log < ActiveRecord::Base
 def self.try_find_logs(options)
  a = options.map do |k,v|
      where(k => v)
  end
  a.inject(:&)
 end   
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@logs = Log.all
@logs = @logs.where(:user_id => params[:user_id]) unless params[:user_id]
@logs = @logs.where(:project_id => params[:project_id]) unless params[:project_id]
@logs = @logs.where(:user_id => params[:customer_id]) unless params[:customer_id]
```

Just in case if you dont know this, the above will fire only one database query.

I would suggest you to use [has_scope](https://github.com/plataformatec/has_scope) gem, which makes the filtering features easily extendable. You can add many more filters easily. And also the gem ignores a param if it is nil(your use case).

```
class Log < ActiveRecord:Base
 scope :user, proc { |u_id| where(:user_id => u_id) }
 ...
end

class LogsController < ApplicationController
  has_scope :user
  def index
     @logs = apply_scopes(Log)
  end
  ...
end
```